# Add both string and int value in one JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Convert user input of meters to feet and inches with the

```
//     following format  (16ft. 4in.).  Disable the button so that
//     the user is forced to clear the form.
```

Problem is that I don't know how to put both string and int value in one text Field, than how can i set them to in if else statement

```
   private void ConversionActionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
   {
         String s =(FourthTextField.getText());
         int val = Integer.parseInt(FifthTextField.getText()); 

         double INCHES = 0.0254001;
         double FEET = 0.3048;
         double meters;

         if(s.equals("in" ) )
         {
             FourthTextField.setText(" " + val*INCHES + "inch");
         }
         else if(s.equals("ft"))
         {
             FourthTextField.setText(" " +val*FEET + "feet");
         }
   }
```

Is it possible to add both string and int value in one `JTextField`?

Comment: `FourthTextField`  Please give controls meaningful names.  Also please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do ...

```
FourthTextField.setText(" " + (val*INCHES) + "inch");
```

or

```
FourthTextField.setText(" " + Double.toString(val*INCHES) + "inch");
```

or

```
FourthTextField.setText(" " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(val*INCHES) + "inch");
```

**Updated**

If all you care about is extract the numeric portion of the text, you could do something like this...

```
String value = "1.9m";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+([.]\\d+)?");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
String match = null;

while (matcher.find()) {

    int startIndex = matcher.start();
    int endIndex = matcher.end();

    match = matcher.group();
    break;

}

System.out.println(match);
```

This will output `1.9`, having stripped of every after the `m`.  This would allow you to extract the numeric element of the `String` and convert to a number for conversion.

This will handle both whole and decimal numbers.

Comment: no , like when i going to ask user , what value they want , for example user fill 16 meters, than how my if else statement know about Value

Comment: Give user to choose from options whether the entered value would be in metre or inch etc. Then get value of options and match them inside if like you are doing

Comment: And about setting both integer and  string, @madprogrammer  has answered already

Comment: @user1970580 Your original question states that the user is entering a value of meters, it makes no sense the to check if they have entered "inches" or "feet" within the field.  Instead, use a `JComboBox` or `JRadioButton`s to provide the choice of conversion

Comment: so is it possible  , suppose if programmer add 10m , so after the clicking the button , JtextField , will show me the both conversion in inches and feets

Comment: @user1970580 yeah that's wat you will have to do in their event parts, check on google about even handling in jcombobox and jradiobutton

Comment: @user1970580 I added an additional example that demonstrates a possible means by which you can extract the numeric portion of the a String...

Comment: thanx...i did it simply , so i just ask the user what values they want to convert , for example user want 16 to convert , so after clicking the program , its display conversion for the both feet and inches.....

Comment: i have one more thing to ask
 0.1524006in 1.8288000000000002ft , how can i get rid of these zeros in text Field

Comment: @user1970580 `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(number)`? - I got `1.829` from `1.8288000000000002`